# Extraer caracteres columna

Tags: python

Quiero limpiar un dataset y no sé como hacerlo con el carácter especial . Para tratar la columna nation lo he hecho creando una función seleccionando las 0:3 últimas cifras, pero en este caso no sé como hacerlo.

Imaginaos que en la columna Player está escrito así:

Ismael Aaneba\Ismael-Aaneba.

¿Cómo hago para quedarme solo con lo anterior al símbolo \ ?

He probado así pero me da error:

```
    def clear_player(c):
        try:
          return c[-0:\]
        except:
          return c

dt['Player'] = dt['Player'].apply(lambda x: clear_player(x))
dt.head(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que realmente quieres hacer es quedarte con una parte del texto de un dataframe. No recorras el dataframe, no es nada óptimo. Lo que puedes hacer es reasignar la columna, haciendo un split y quedándote con la parte izquierda. Te dejo el enlace del [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Por lo que yo haría sería un simple apply de la columna que deseas con un split, de esta manera:

```
df["Player"] = df["Player"].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
```

De esta manera, separas el string con el caracter que tu desees en una lista, y como quieres la primera parte, te quedas con la posición 0 y lo tienes ya hecho.

Espero te haya servido de ayuda. Un saludo